# Extract specific data from field in Access table

Tags: string, function, ms-access, vba

Every 2 weeks I need to import an excel file into an access 2007 database. The 2nd cell in the excel file A2 contains always different information. It always start with AS OF PAY PERIOD XX, where XX stands for the pay period. When imported into an access table I need to extract the pay period and it seems that the pay period is always in position 18, a payperiod is always 2 chars in length. Is there an easy way with a string function to extract that information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/mid-function-HA001228881.aspx

Returns a Variant (String) containing a specified number of characters from a string.

Syntax

Mid(string, start [, length ] )

The Mid function syntax has these arguments :

string - Required. string expression from which characters are returned. If string contains Null, Null is returned.

start - Required. Long - Character position in string at which the part to be taken begins. If start is greater than the number of characters in string, Mid returns a zero-length string ("").

length - Optional. Variant (Long) - Number of characters to return. If omitted or if there are fewer than length characters in the text (including the character at start), all characters from the start position to the end of the string are returned.

Use the MID statment within a query, a SQL statement, or on the field data element from a recordset process.